# How to add app names and paths to list in JSON file through electron-store

Tags: javascript, json, electron

I'm trying to make a simple game launcher. Launches one specific game and tool apps from the list that is user customizable. Using electron-store and showOpenDialog, I select a tool executable, showOpenDialog takes a full path from Dialog and then it's made into var_toolName (simplified file name, path.basename+regex+replace to cut out part before first non-letter character) and var_toolPath (just full path stringified with join()). Those both variables are stored in config file through electron-store. One problem is I don't know how to append next tool executable to the list, instead replacing, and I've been trying for few days.

What I expect JSON list of apps inside config.json to be looking (just an idea, not specific coding):

- tools: *(so I know it's a part of config.json related to list of apps, overall config.json has few simple stuff stored such as window position, game executable path)*

  - toolName1

    - toolPath1
  - toolName2

    - toolPath2
  - toolName3

    - toolPath3

and etc.,

Two roles of this JSON list is to make a HTMl list inside electron app (so user knows what tools are going to be launched together with game and, optionally, could toggle on/off specific tools and delete, I haven't reached that part yet, I'm guessing that would require some work on electrons-store and ipcMain/Renderer). Second role would be including full paths of tools to be launched together with game executable

Script for selecting tool executables and saving stuff to config.json:

```
const AppConfig = require('electron-store')
const appConfig = new AppConfig()
const path = require('path') //for executable/game folder path manipulations

//*****************************
// add tools
//*****************************

// 1. detect button click
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', addTool);

//2. select tool exe + save path
function addTool() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
            title: 'Select tool executable.',
            filters: [{
                name: 'Tool start file',
                extensions: ['exe', 'jar']
            }],
            properties: ['openFile']
        },
        (exeFromDialog) => {
            var var_exeToolPath = exeFromDialog.join(); //removes square brackets
            var var_toolName = path.basename(var_exeToolPath).split(/[/._-]/g)[0];
            //path.basename removes path until file, split+regex takes only first part until first character (one of ._/)

            appConfig.set(
                "tools", {
                    "toolName": var_toolName,
                    "toolPath": var_exeToolPath
                }
            )
        })
}
```

How current config.json look (the 'tools' part just gets replaced, instead being appended)

```
{
    "winPosition": {
        "x": 1130,
        "y": 480,
        "width": 202,
        "height": 602
    },
    "exePOEPath": [
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Grinding Gear Games\\Path of Exile\\PathOfExile_x64.exe"
    ],
    "tools": {
        "toolName": "tool3",
        "toolPath": "D:\\tool3.jar"
    }
}
```

Current look of app (list is just a fake filler):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get available tools first the append your new tool to it and save
See bellow,

```
let _tools = appConfig.get("tools");
if(!_tools){
    _tools = {};
}

_tools[var_toolName] = var_exeToolPath;

appConfig.set(
    "tools", _tools
)
```

So expected output will be,

```
{
   .
   .
   .,
   "tools": {
       "tool1": "D:\\tool1.jar",
       "tool2": "D:\\tool2.jar",
       "tool3": "D:\\tool3.jar"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell what "_tools[var_toolName] = var_exeToolPath;" does?

Comment: @namelessone it creates a key using var_toolName and assign the value var_exeToolPath to it.

Comment: I've tried to convert JSON into HTML list, but seems without property identifiers (let's say `"toolName"` for `var_toolName` and `"toolPath"` for `var_exeToolPath`), I can't extract only toolNames from JSON list to inject into HTML list, and toolPath could be probably needed to let app know which executables it's supposed to launch together with game. It's the line I use for generating list items `output += "<li>" + toolList.tools[i].toolName + "</li>";`. Unless there's a way to extract keys (`var_toolName`) and values (`var_exeToolpath`) separately without relying on identifiers?